# Truncate text of Twitter Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to truncate the text of the Bootstrap carousel `.carousel-caption` element. I am using [shave.js](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/shave) to truncate the text. However, the truncating only works on the first `.carousel-caption` element.

I`ve created a jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xela84/dpnpo4o7/1/)

When I remove the CSS class `carousel-inner` from the carousel, the truncating works perfectly on booth `.carousel-caption` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not pretty sure about the issue, but I think it's due to the dynamic behavior of the carousel so the shave code will only work on the first caption because it's visible and **its height is set** so your code should also be dynamic to call the shave funcion for each slide.

An idea is to use the event provided by the carousel component and call the shave function there.

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $(".carousel-caption").shave(70);
})
```

> **slid.bs.carousel** : This event is fired when the carousel has completed
>   its slide transition. <sup>[ref](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel-events)</sup>

Full code : https://jsfiddle.net/dpnpo4o7/2/

---

I used the jQuery version of the plugin in the code above but it works the same with the JS version:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  shave(".carousel-caption", 70);
})
```

Full code : https://jsfiddle.net/dpnpo4o7/3/

Answer (score 1):

I went through the fiddle. And shave must be finding those second captions but since it is invisible at that moment, it is failing to do that.

Solution: You might want to capture the prev and next events and then try your code.